# How to read string and corresponding int from a file in C++?

Tags: c++, string, file-io, int

I am working on a two-part project for a class, and have finished the first section but have run into trouble on the second part. For the first part, I was able to read a list from a file and into a vector to manipulate with various functions. A list from this section would look like:

```
banana

apple

pineapple

grapefruit

orange

pear

grape

lime

lemon
```

Which I was able to complete. For this first part, I simply have a vector of strings. However, the second part introduces a quantity to these values. The list for this section would follow as:

```
foo 5

bar 4

baz 2

boz 1

foo 3
```

At this point, I'm not sure how to read for item as a string and a corresponding int which follows it. For items that are repeated, they're supposed to be add to the original value for that item. I was planning on having a vector of objects which had a name and a quantity to manipulate but I need to read the file first. Thanks for any help!

This is how I was originally reading the file

```
if (fileIn.is_open()){
//file opened successfully so we are here 


    ifstream inf(fileName + ".txt");
    string word;

    while (inf >> word)
    {
        currentSet.push_back(word);
    }
```

Comment: Are there any restrictions on the strings for the items?  (In particular, can they contain white space?)

Comment: Are you having trouble **reading** this data, or are you asking what kind of **data structure** would be good?

Comment: How do you read strings? Do you use the ifstream extraction operator (>>)?

Comment: should `foo 5` and `foo 3` result in 8x foo?

Comment: How the list is given is how it will be tested. The strings will all be lowercase characters with no special characters. Once the file reaches foo 3 the object for foo should contain a value of 8. I edited my question with the code I was originally using. My problem is reading the int following the string in the file.

Comment: @InflictedOwned What's the problem with reading the `int` after the word.  If the word consists of only lower case letters (no white space), then `>>` will work for reading the word, and of course, `>>` always works for reading an `int`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just do something like:

```
map<string, int> vals; //or some other data structure
ifstream ifs(somefile);
string word;
int i;

while(ifs >> word >> i) {
  vals[word] += i;
}
```

Simply read them one after the other. Of course you can add error checking as you want. But I recommend the map data structure for easy access and manipulation.

Comment: this is pretty much exactly what I was going to post in a second. +1

Comment: I've never used `std::map` before, but is `vals[word]` guaranteed to be initialized to zero, or would you need to explicitly add that part in as well?

Comment: For ints yes it will. It will default initialize the value.